# use conditional statement with theme Android DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I wan to set the theme of root view based on a condition, but faced error.

what I used:

```xml
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
        android:theme="@{ isDarker ? @style/DarkerCardThem : @style/LighterCardThem}">
```

error:

`Could not find identifier 'DarkerCardThem' Check that the identifier is spelled correctly, and that no <import> or <variable> tags are missing`

the style:

```xml
    <style name="DarkerCardThem">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/darker_card_color</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@BindingAdapter` for this purpose.

```
@BindingAdapter("setThemeC")
fun ConstraintLayout.setThemeC(isDarker : Boolean) {
    /*.....*/
}
```

After that in your code:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
        setThemeC="@{isDarker}">
```

Use: `setThemeC(Boolean)` to enable the functionality.

`Could not find identifier 'DarkerCardThem' Check that the identifier is spelled correctly, and that no <import> or <variable> tags are missing`

It's clear that, you can use those tags in the `<layout></layout>` section not `<style>`

Comment: As `theme` can not be changed by code so i did it at XML level. 
So next question what to write inside `setThemC`

Answer (score -1):

hello mahmoud i think it's impasbole to do that but if you want to change theme you can do it in your code before setContentView

```
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

Comment: I want to use custom theme not dark, light modes.